Node cron isn't sending my task through discord
I tried to make a scheduled message with my discord bot using node-cron (discord.js) but the message doesn't seem to work.
When I use the console.log function to send the task into the console, it comes out fine, but when i try to make the message send into discord through the bot, nothing sends. Is there something I'm missing?
My code:
cron.schedule('56 17 * * *', function() {

    const randomPosmsg = require('./posmessages.js');
    const randomPospic = require('./posmessages.js');
    const posEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#ffc7fd")
        .setDescription(randomPosmsg)
        .setImage(randomPospic)
        .setFooter({ 
            text: 'use /positive to suggest a positive quote', 
            iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1055129933531332648/1246430606376833024/Pngtreepink_smooth_bow_5675840.png?ex=665c5c76&is=665b0af6&hm=4826e8f7cc66a2f9d5969875a26f6cc2e2a0b1d3c8056e0ab3e071857f1291b0&"
        })
        .setTimestamp()

        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "900689263241330708")
        channel.send({content: "<@&973909281206333460>", embeds: [posEmbed]})
    });


Have you initialized your client correctly?
Also try to add a error catch when sending the message:
channel.send({ content: "<@&973909281206333460>", embeds: [posEmbed] })
    .then(() => console.log('Message sent successfully!'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error sending message:', err));


thank you for the reply!
I'm pretty sure I've initialsied the client correctly with:
`client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
cron.schedule('20 07 * * *', function() {
...
});`
i added the error catch and again, nothing happened. I don't get errors nor do I get a message
